# Assigning offices to companies for a certain period

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to write a program which rents offices to companies for given start and end dates. We have n number of offices. Companies will make a call to see if there is an available office from **startDate** to **endDate**

If a rental request is received and can be accepted we accept it immediately. Don’t wait for future requests.

If there are multiple options(offices) to rent, we rent the office with the smallest id.

Days are limited to 365 and n<=1000

[Example Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saEwz.png)

When we have 2 office rooms: requests (0, 2), (0,4), (5,6), (4,5), (6,8) arrives we accept first 3 and reject (4,5) because there are no vacancies. Then accept (6,8).

I considered to use Lists but is there a efficient way to do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework assignment and while it does ask a relevant question, it is too broad

Comment: @DanielFarrell what do you mean by too broad?

Comment: @DanielFarrell It is not a homework and I am not asking for implementation or so. I am just trying to find ideas to do it efficiently.

Comment: "I considered to use Lists but is there a efficient way to do this?" Lists are used in just about every computer program.  But "Lists" is not a solution to this problem.  Lists would almost certainly be *involved* in any solution.  Get lists working, and if you want to ask about a more efficient way, bring back the code you wrote and folks will be happy to discuss it.

Comment: My script is not small to post it here but my idea is this: I tried to keep a list of reserved offices, each office has a list of reservations. Once there is a new rental request: I first check if dates overlap with an existing rental. When it is detected that there is an available office in my list, I add this new rental to this office's reservations list, if there is no avaialable slots in already reserved offices and I am able to reserve another office, I call createOffice() and add it to my offices list. Also add request to office's reservation list. But I didn't like this time complexity.

Comment: Since the intervals for a single office are not allowed to overlap, you can build a binary search tree to keep track of the assignments for a single office. To search the tree, if the rental request overlaps the root's dates, reject the request (for this office). Otherwise, if the start date is greater than the root's end date, move to the right child. Otherwise, move to the left child.

Comment: @user3386109 thank you very much. I will try this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.